# Animación deja de tener transition

Tags: javascript, css, animacion-css

Intento hacer un cierre de un elemento de forma divertida, pero que tarde un segundo en realizarse cada parte de la animación:

```js
let tgl = document.querySelector('.toggle-container'),
        con = document.getElementById('curious-fact');
    tgl.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        con.style.width = '0';//se cierra correctamente, tarda un segundo en completar la accion
        setTimeout(()=>{
            con.style.height = '0';//lo hace de golpe, deja de tener transition
        },1500);
        /*setTimeout(()=>{
            con.style.top = '-1000px';//ya no tenia transition, pero despues de que se cerrase en vertical, tiene que esconderse
        },2000);*/
    });
```

```css
    html, body, .container, .content, .img, .title, .context, .sub-context{margin:0;padding:0;}



    .container{
        width: 1000px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 50px auto;
        padding: 25px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        border-left: 20px solid black;
        border-right: 20px solid black;
        background-color: #F4F4F4;
        transition: 1s;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .content{width: 1000px;}

    .img{
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 15px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .img img{transition: 0.6s;border-radius: 15px;}
    .img:hover img{transition: 0.6s;transform: scale(1.1);}

    .title{
        width: 675px;
        height: 50px;
        margin-left: 25px;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .title h1{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 15px 0 ;
        max-width: 675px;
        height: 20px;
        font-size: 18.72px;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        text-shadow: -1px 1px 0px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);
    }

    .context{
        width: 675px;
        height: 225px;
        margin: 25px 0 0 25px;
        float: left;
    }

    .context p{
        width: 650px;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 12.5px auto;
    }

    .sub-context{
        width: 1000px;
        height: 175px;
        margin-top: 25px;
        float: left;
    }

    .sub-context p{
        width: 975px;
        height: 150px;
        margin: 12.5px auto;
    }

    .toggle-container{
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 50px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: black;
        color:white;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container" id="curious-fact">
        <div class="content">
            <div>
                <div class="img"></div>
                <div class="title"></div>
                <div class="context"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="toggle-container">X</div>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </div>
```

El caso es que, tras la ejecución de la primera animación, deja de funcionar la propiedad transition. ¿Por qué pasa esto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te estás topando con una limitación de las transiciones: necesitan saber de dónde parten y hasta dónde van:

Con el ancho (width) no tienes problema porque está definido en los estilos:

```
.container{
    width: 1000px;
    ...
}
```

Pero el alto depende del contenido, con lo que no está definido en `con.style.height`, sino que es un valor que se calcula dinámicamente al renderizar.

Una solución a tu problema es obtener el valor real de este campo y aplicarlo después del renderizado, o justo antes de iniciar la transición.
Te pongo un ejemplo en el que podrás ver que funciona sólo si haces ese cálculo (al pulsar el botón antes de cerrar tu elemento).

El funcionamiento es simple: obtenemos el alto calculado con `window.getComputedStyle(elem)`, que obtiene un objeto similar al que verías en `elem.style` pero con los valores *calculados* (computed).

```js
const con = document.getElementById('curious-fact');
const tgl = document.querySelector('.toggle-container');
tgl.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  con.style.width = '0';//se cierra correctamente, tarda un segundo en completar la accion
  setTimeout(()=>{
      con.style.height = '0';//lo hace de golpe, deja de tener transition
  },1500);
});
    
 document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',() => {
  const actualHeight = window.getComputedStyle(con).height
  console.log('Height:', actualHeight);
  con.style.height = actualHeight;
 });
```

```css
html, body, .container, .content, .img, .title, .context, .sub-context{
  margin:0;padding:0;
}
.container{
    width: 300px;        
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-left: 20px solid black;
    border-right: 20px solid black;
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
    transition: 1s;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content{width: 300px;}

.img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.img img{transition: 0.6s;border-radius: 15px;}
.img:hover img{transition: 0.6s;transform: scale(1.1);}

.context{
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 25px 0 0 25px;
    float: left;
}

.toggle-container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<button>Añade height al style</button>
<div class="container" id="curious-fact">
        <div class="content">
            <div>
                <div class="img"></div>
                <div class="title"></div>
                <div class="context"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="toggle-container">X</div>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Por tanto, cuando quiera hacer la ejecución del traslado hacia fuera de la pantalla, osea, con.style.top = '-1000px'; Qué tendría que tener definido ahí?